# Laravel ORM обновление столбца

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте!
Возможно ли в Laravel посредством ORM произвести update() в базе данных без занесения в переменную?
Пытаюсь вот так, не выходит:

```
public function update()
{
Auth::user->price = $price;
Auth::user()->name = 'Гром';
Auth::user()->update();
}
```

Возможно ли решить мой вопрос без занесения в переменную $user

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял задачу, Вы что-то напутали, не обязательно заносить в переменную, прочтите как работает update() - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queries.

Answer (score 0):

Посредством Eloquent ORM, нет, так как она предполагает, создание объекта класса модели. Но при помощи Query Builder можно.
Ссылка на документацию: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Comment: А вообще углубитесь в ООП, чтобы не задавать такие вопросы в дальнейшем.